# How to read aliases in a ksh script

Tags: alias, ksh

I have some global aliases defined in my `~/.profile` file.
To read them from a bash script, I'd use:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.profile
```

However, in ksh this does not work because it does not have a `shopt` command.
How do I read the aliases from a file in ksh?

Comment: Do you need to do something special in `ksh`? It seems, the alias are expanded in non-interactive shells, too.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `ksh` because I have a `for` loop in the script and I need to call variables from that loop, `bash` does not support this.

Comment: Uh, sorry, that was a missunderstanding. I did a quick test with a `#!/bin/ksh` script, therein sourced an alias file and used an alias with no problem. So my question was, do you need a `shopt` equivalent after all? Or: What _does not work_?

Comment: Have you figured it out?